# Update only fields with text using ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I've an update view that is based on `ModelForm` , I'm using `instance` to update the current row , but the problem is user maynot need to update all the fields. but when the form saves data . it saves everything and gives me blank fields ( which user didn't fill). Here are my codes :

**forms.py**

```
class EditYellowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    business_title = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(
                                         attrs={
                                             'placeholder': 'New Title',
                                             'style': 'width: 100%; max-width: 500px'
                                         }
                                     )
                                     )

    contact_address = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                      widget=forms.TextInput(
                                          attrs={
                                              'placeholder': 'New Address',
                                              'style': 'width: 100%; max-width: 500px'
                                          }
                                      )
                                      )

    class Meta:
        model = YellowPages
        fields = ['business_title', 'contact_address']
```

**views.py**

```
def yellow_edit(request, pk):
    current_yellow_ad = get_object_or_404(YellowPages, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        edit_yellow_form = EditYellowForm(instance=current_yellow_ad, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if edit_yellow_form.is_valid():
            instance = edit_yellow_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('yellow_pages')
    else:
        edit_yellow_form = EditYellowForm(instance=current_yellow_ad, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

    context = {
        'edit_yellow_form': edit_yellow_form,
        'current_yellow_ad': current_yellow_ad,
    }
    return render(request, 'yellow_pages/edit.html', context)
```

**the model** in case it is needed:

```
class YellowPages(models.Model):
    type_of_business_chioces = (
        ('service', 'service '),
        ('product ', 'product '),
    )
    business_title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    contact_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(validators=[URLValidator()], max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(YelllowPagesCategory, on_delete=CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    owned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    otp = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If  user may not fill some fields and they are blank ¿You don't want this to happen?. In case you don't want this behaviour, configure your model accordingly. But I think you must explain better what you are asking.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes, that is exactly what I mean. the item is already listed but what if the user only needs to change the title. not all the info!
The form updates everything mentioned in the `fields=` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to update only the fields that is not empty in the form. So you can use [update_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) argument. You should pass the name of the fields you want to update as a list. Something like this should work:

```
    if edit_yellow_form.is_valid():
        instance = edit_yellow_form.save(commit=False)
        form_data = edit_yellow_form.cleaned_data
        fields_to_update = [field for field in form_data if form_data[field] != '']
        instance.save(update_fields=fields_to_update)
        return redirect('yellow_pages')
```